# How to access abstract Server class of MicrosoftAnalysisServices?

Tags: c#, server, ssas, visual-studio-2019, analysisservices

I am trying to implement Dynamic Cube partition using SSAS and Visual Studio in the script task component. I am trying to implement following code snippet:

```
Server srv = new Server();
```

However, It keeps giving me error stating abstract class obj cannot be created. I therefore created a Servertest class and implemented Server class.
An example of the error would be:

```
    Error   CS0534  'Servertest' does not implement inherited abstract member
    Error   CS0534  'Servertest' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Server.CreateSessionTrace()' 
 and so on for very method inside Server class
```

My entire code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core;
namespace ST_f9f3ba4b76c64ba5bbe76f4be0e05d3c
{


    public class Servertest : Server {
        public void Connect(String s) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();

        }
    }

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        Byte[] dataByte;
        int IsPartitionExists = 0;

        public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here

            try
            {
                String  Database_Name = Dts.Variables["User::Database_Name"].Value.ToString();
                String  Cube_Name = Dts.Variables["User::Cube_Name"].Value.ToString();
                String  Measure_Group_Name = Dts.Variables["User::Measure_Group_Name"].Value.ToString();
                String PartitionName = Dts.Variables["User::PartitionName"].Value.ToString();

                ConnectionManager ConnManager = Dts.Connections[Database_Name];
                String ServerName = ConnManager.Properties["ServerName"].GetValue(ConnManager).ToString();
                String DatabaseName = ConnManager.Properties["InitialCatalog"].GetValue(ConnManager).ToString();
                String CubeName = Cube_Name;
                String MeasureGroupName = Measure_Group_Name;

                IsPartitionExists = VerifyPartition(ServerName, DatabaseName, CubeName, MeasureGroupName, PartitionName);
                if (IsPartitionExists == -1)
                {
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                }
                else 
                {
                    Dts.Variables["User::IsPartitionExists"].Value = IsPartitionExists;
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                //Dts.Log("Error Message: "+ ex.Message,0);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }



        public int VerifyPartition(String ServerName, String DatabaseName, String CubeName, String MeasureGroupName,String ParitionName) 
        {

            string ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + ServerName + ";Catalog=" + DatabaseName + ";";

            string ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + ServerName + ";Catalog=" + DatabaseName + ";";
            Servertest t = new Servertest();
            t.Connect(ConnectionString);
                ................
            return 1;
        }



    }
}
```

It is asking me to implement all methods of server class. Please help me find a solution to this issue
Thank you!!

Comment: The Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.Server class is abstract, but its implementation Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server is not. Did you perhaps mean to import (or qualify) the latter rather than the former?

Comment: Instead of importing Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core; i need to import Microsoft.AnalysisServices;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of research using different tutorials online, I figured that I am required to import Microsoft.AnalysisServices Instead of Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core. By changing my import statement I was able to use the Server.Connect method.
Thank you for taking time to review my problem